# Accessing Swift variables added by Folder reference

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Actually I spend around 3 hours in this simple problem and googled it a lot but no way.
My question is very simple. I want to add a directory as a "Folder Reference" to my Swift xCode project. But no way to access them.

I don't need to add then using Group Reference, any suggestions?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: No `import` needed! :)

Comment: I got the "Use of unresolved identifier" error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: if you are using folder references, there is no way to import them and you must reference them using the full directory path.

EX:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "Images/Icons/GoPago")
```

That is the only way. Depending on what your project requires, I would suggest using groupings like below.

The problem is that you are using folders and not grouping. There is no import needed. You just need to take everything in the folder and "group" it through xCode. Then you will be able to access it in your code. It should look as a yellow folder when you group it in there. Like so:

[image]

and it should look like this:

[image]

if you are copying over a directory, you would want to make sure to select create groups as follows. :

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "group it through xCode"?

Comment: @Elsammak just make sure any folder you have/make is yellow and you should be fine.

Comment: This works for individual files not directory. Notice that I want to add them as a "Reference folder" (i.e Blue folder in xCode)

Comment: Take the directory and select all fires in it and group them. That is how it works in xCode

Comment: @Elsammak, check my updated answer on how to copy a number of directories over.

Comment: I added how to reference things from a directory as well above.

Comment: @Elsammak, did that answer your question?

Comment: yes I follow your steps and it did the job. I got it now. Thank you :)

Comment: @Elsammak, please accept the answer if it was helpful. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

import TestFolder works on frameworks not on group creation , actually groups are shown only for good user experience for the developers, If you right click on groups you will not find any references.