# Unable to use third party Swift class extensions

Tags: swift

I am trying to use the Swift extensions located at https://github.com/goktugyil/EZSwiftExtensions. The README states

> 1.Download and drop '/Sources' in your project.
>   2.Congratulations!

I have followed these directions to the best of my understanding and have dropped the Sources folder into my project:

[image: Project]

However, when I try to use one of the extensions, *self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()*, I get the error "Value of type 'LoginVC' has no member 'hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround'". I'm very much new to Swift, so I'm really not sure where I'm going wrong with this one

Copy of my code:

```
import UIKit
class LoginVC: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround(); // <--- Error produced here!
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.emailField.delegate = self;
    self.passwordField.delegate = self;
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    return false
}
/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

Comment: UIViewControllerExtensions.swift must be included in your build target. Have you verified this?

Comment: @bneely I added the folder to the project target when I added the files. Is the build target a separate option?

Comment: The problem is your Sources folder is being imported as a folder, not a group (blue folder, not yellow folder). Make sure "create groups" is selected when you drag the folder into Xcode (delete the reference and re-drag in)

Comment: Within Xcode, select the file "UIViewControllerExtensions.swift" in the project navigator (it's the file icon in the left column of the main window, called the Navigator). Then open the right column (called Utilities) and ensure your app is checked under the section labeled "Target Membership".  [See screenshot](http://imgur.com/NW2WlZm)

Comment: @originaluser2 This is correct, thank you. Haven't used SE much. How should I go about closing the question?

Comment: @Arm1stice Might as well just close it as a [duplicate of this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35033172/2976878).